# Не работает RewriteRule на удаленном сервере

Tags: .htaccess

Есть правило в .htaccess для сокрытия всех txt файлов

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*\.txt$ /index.php
```

На локалке все работает - как загружаю на сервер, так ничего не работает, как будто нет этого правила, и все txt файлы можно просмотреть

Остальные правила (а их много) работают, например

```
RewriteRule ^module/([0-9A-Za-z]+)(/?)+$ /index.php?module=$1 [L,QSA]
```

В чем может быть причина?

В начале файла у меня стоит вот что

```
php_value display_errors 1
php_value error_reporting 2047
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
```

Comment: В .htaccess добавляли директиву 
RewriteEngine on ?

Comment: @cheops да, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Собственно, все было довольно просто. Вот что мне ответили в тех поддержке хостинга.

> Статические файлы, например TXT отдаются не Apache, а Nginx, который игнорирует настройки из .htaccess. Если данная проблема для вас критична, можем перенаправить все запросы на Apache, ваши правила в .htaccess заработают, но это может негативно сказаться на производительности сайта.